# Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully -- What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I don't really use Python, so excuse me if my problem is evident. I have created a virtual environment in cmd using `python -m venv aitest` command. Then I cloned a repo into the venv using `git clone link.git` (link stands for the link I used obviously). Then I went into the created folder and I keep trying to `pip install -r requirements_versions.txt` but I always get the same error seen below. Could anyone help please? Answers are much appreciated!!

```
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [54 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      writing lib\PyYAML.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to lib\PyYAML.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to lib\PyYAML.egg-info\top_level.txt
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\bagda\aitest\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\bagda\aitest\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\bagda\aitest\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 288, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 321, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 329, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 551, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 589, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 112, in add_defaults
          super().add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
          self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 204, in get_source_files
        File "C:\Users\bagda\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-u7v7rb6h\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: cython_sources
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Update to `pyyaml==6.0.1` in `requirements_versions.txt`. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+cython_sources BTW, is it https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui ?

Comment: Thank you so much! Almost, It's actually https://github.com/lllyasviel/Fooocus . However, I encountered a new problem, which gives me Error: metadata-generation-failed , do you have any idea what could cause it?
I can see that it has something to do with "Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error"

Comment: If you have a different question ask it separately. Provide all related information — what commands did you run and what is their text output and errors. In the current form the question is meaningless: it's just "I have some problem".

Comment: I understand, I posted it as a separate question. Thank you for your help!